# Have I incorrectly fed chain into the rear mech hanger

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear

So I've had to change my chain because my indicator says it's worn. It did also seem to stretch quite a lot more then the new chain.

I think I may have fed it into the rear mech hanger incorrectly since it now skips every time I pedal instead of occasionally.[image]
+

On my rear mech hanger there is clearly a metal tab going across the width of the mech. Does the chain have to go underneath it or over it.

If it's under, it seems impossible unless I take the bottom jockey wheel out. but I don't want to dismantle and make matters worse.

I can see why this can be confusing. The picture above I omitted the chain on purpose so it was clear what I was referring to

I had it routed like this

[image]

Is it correct now?

How about my front chain rings. They don't look right to me but am not a mechanic.

[image: Chain links]

[Chain link image.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13JVjcyi5AZHJAEMKo6jWL2lYcje2WYgw9g)

Comment: There is typically a (seemingly senseless) "tongue" attached to one of the side pieces of the derailer, about midway between the pulleys.  I don't recall, without looking at a unit, whether the chain goes "over" or "under", but when properly routed the chain should not rub against the "tongue".  Obviously you can get the chain on the wrong side if you take the chain off and then reinstall it, but I've also had the chain relocate itself somehow to the "wrong" side when futzing with a wheel, trying to get it installed.  If there's enough slack in the chain you can generally work it past.

Comment: BTW, your cogs appear to be worn, but not to the point where I'd expect you to have trouble with them.  I'm kind of wondering if you got your chain length correct.  The new chain should have the **same number of links** as the old one.  (It should be shorter, since the old chain is "stretched".)

Comment: if I have badly worn front chain ring, can it affect the rear deraileur shifting?

Comment: A badly worn front ring will generally only affect rear shifting if the bad ring is "hooked" and causes the chain to catch intermittently.  (Usually the effects of "hooked" cogs on the rear are lessened by changing out the chain, but, as you may have discovered, changing the chain when the front ring is hooked tends to make matters worse.)

Comment: So are u saying i need a new crankset? I want to solve my problem so i can lake district

Comment: That front ring is fairly worn, but doesn't appear to be badly hooked.  It may be hooked in spots, however.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.  I went to the shop I got my bike from the mechanic said "chain too long". He took a link out. Having measured and counted links againest my old chain, thats what I was about to do last night but was unsure.

Comment: Daniel if you answer to this I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your chain is set up correctly in the second picture. It should go over the metal tab.

The reason your chain is skipping is probably because your cogs are worn out. If this is the case, you should replace your freewheel/cassette to avoid destroying your new chain.

Comment: It's generally easier to remove/reinstall a pulley than to "break" and rejoin the chain.

Comment: That statement is only true if your chain doesn't have some company's equivalent of the quicklink.  In my experience (with a replacement chain) that means it is false the majority of the time.  Given there is a quicklink showing in this picture, it's false in this case.

Comment: @SuspendedUser I'm not sure which statement you're talking about... are you saying it should go under the metal tab?

Comment: No.  I was talking about the idea of removing pulleys to install/correct a chain.  That's belt drive insanity talk there.

Comment: A chain may also skip if it is too long. Have you matched the length of the new chain (number of links) to the previous chain?